# Ruby uniniatialized constant in Calabash Step

Tags: ruby, calabash-android

I am writing some interface tests using Cucumber as skeleton for Android-Calabash. The tests are written in Ruby.

I am receiving the following execution error:

> uninitialized constant MultiTouchGesture

The code generating it is:

```
require 'calabash-android/calabash_steps'
require 'calabash-android/gestures'

        When(/^When I touch the spaceship and an asteroid at the same time$/) do
            gest = []
            multi_touch = MultiTouchGesture.new(gest)
            gestures.add_touch(touch("* id:'spaceship'"), 0)
            gestures.add_touch(touch("* id:'asteroid'"), 1)
        end
```

I guess Ruby does not find gestures.rb where MultiTouchGesture class is, even if I have imported it using 'require'. I have checked for gestures.rb and it is not missing in my computer, it is in the following path:

> C:\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\calabash-android-0.9.0\lib\calabash-android

What can I do to make Ruby find the class?

Here is the documentation for MultiTouchGesture class:
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/calabash-android/Calabash/Android/Gestures/MultiTouchGesture

Thank you,

Héctor

Comment: Does your original code contain `require 'calabash-android/gestures'`?
If ruby wouldn't be able to load this file it would throw the error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- 'calabash-android/gestures'`.

Comment: It did not contain the require, I already have included it, but same error is shown.

Comment: What if you use `Calabash::Android::Gestures::MultiTouchGesture.new(gest)` instead of `MultiTouchGesture.new(gest)`

Comment: Now it seems to be working. Thank you very much! Is there a way I could reduce Calabash::Android::Gestures::MultiTouchGesture to a shorter resolution operator?

Comment: You can try to use `Gestures::MultiTouchGesture.new(gest)`, not sure if all namespaces are loaded. Alternatively, you can put `include Calabash::Android::Gestures` after requires part, then just `MultiTouchGesture.new(gest)` should work.